# jupyter notebook - Why notebook doesn't format this dictionary well?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm using *classification_report* function which is supposed to return a dictionary, but it doesn't return a well-structured one. So how can I print it well in jupyter notebook?

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
classification_report(test_preds, y_test)
```

Here is my output:

```
'              precision    recall  f1-score   support\n\n           0       0.81      0.97      0.88      1653\n
           1       0.76      0.28      0.41       533\n\n    accuracy                           0.80      2186\n   macro avg
       0.78      0.63      0.65      2186\nweighted avg       0.79      0.80      0.77      2186\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `print(classification_report(test_preds, y_test))`